# Metro App range input, change text in tooltip?

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, winjs, windows-store-apps

I would like to set the text in the tool tip that appears over sliders i Win8/WinJS/Metro/Modern UI (input type="range"), but I can't find any info on how to do so.

The only information I can seem to find is that it can be styled through:

```
some_selector::-ms-tooltip
{
    display: none;
}
```

But I can't change the text through .text(t)/.html(t) using jQuery.

So the question is, how would I select the tooltip element so that I can set the text?

Comment: I'm looking for exactly the same thing... Did you have any luck by the time?? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I forgot about this question. No I never found any solution.